# Confusion about data types in Haskell

Tags: haskell, types

I have to write a simple pi approximation and I did and it works fine, but in the task it says to write a function with the header "pi_approx :: Int -> Double".

My code:

```
pi_approx x = sqrt (pi2_approx(x))

pi2_approx x = 
    if x/= 1
    then (6 /(x*x)) + (pi2_approx(x-1))
    else (6/(1*1))
```

However my function works fine without "pi_approx :: Int -> Double", but when i try to use this declaration I always get the type error:

pi_approx.hs:10:14: error:

- Couldn't match expected type `Double' with actual type` Int'
- In the expression: (+) (6 / (x * x)) (pi2_approx (x - 1))
  In the expression:
  if x /= 1 then
  (+) (6 / (x * x)) (pi2_approx (x - 1))
  else
  (6 / (1 * 1))
  In an equation for `pi2_approx':
  pi2_approx x
  = if x /= 1 then
  (+) (6 / (x * x)) (pi2_approx (x - 1))
  else
  (6 / (1 * 1))
  |
  10 |         then (+) (6 /(x*x)) (pi2_approx(x-1))
  |              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

I tried to use fromIntegral in various ways and if I run the function without declaration I checked the type of the solution, which is: "(Floating a, Eq a) => a"

As I understand Double should be an instance of Floating so I don´t understand why it wont compile.

I am very new at haskell and it seems I don´t understand the core concept of data types and constraints. I can´t seem to find any simple and good documentation/explanation on the topic though. Maybe someone here can help me understand based on this example :)

Comment: because `x` is an `Int`, hence `x * x` is also an `Int`, and you can not use an `Int` for `(/) :: Floating a => a -> a -> a`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

because `x` is an `Int`, hence `x * x` is also an `Int`, and you can not use an `Int` for `(/) :: Floating a => a -> a -> a`.

You need to convert this to a `Double`, for example with [**`fromIntegral :: (Integral a, Num b) => a -> b`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:fromIntegral):

```
pi2_approx :: Int -> Double
pi2_approx 1 = 6
pi2_approx x = 6 / fromIntegral (x*x) + pi2_approx (x-1)
```

For a large number of iterations, it gives a result close to *π<sup>2</sup>*:

```
Prelude> sqrt (pi2_approx 10000)
3.1414971639472147
```